# Want to change request url but remain transparent to application

Tags: php, nginx

I just did a whole heap of dev work and used a url similar to below...

```
http://192.168.1.10/
```

The thing is though, my client wants to run 2 seperate applications using the same IP address. So essentially you would have one application running on http://192.168.1.1/ and the other application will be runing on http://192.168.1.1/sales.

I tried to do a proxy_pass to my other application with the following...

```
location /sales {
    proxy_pass        http://192.168.1.10;
}
```

When I visit the page I am being brought to the applications 404 page. I can understand why this is occurring, because the application is treating the 'sales' as part of the uri and that doesn't belong to any routes in my application.

Is there any way I can accomplish accessing the webpage with the URL http://192.168.1.1/sales however the application views it as http://192.168.1.1? I would like to accomplish this without having to touching my application.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive.

Try:

```
location /sales/ {
    proxy_pass        http://192.168.1.10/;
    ...
}
```

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass